# Is there a way to calculate the percentage of NA's in each column of a dataframe, but with the df split into separate groups?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm looking to determine the ratio of missing values in each column of a dataframe, split by the separate groups in that dataframe.

I'm quite new to R, so I haven't had much success so far.
Here's an example dataset to test it out on:

```
df <- data.frame(
  programme = c('A','B','B','A','B','C','C','C','C','A'),
  v1 = c(24,NA,NA,45,NA,23,22,23,45,23),
  v2 = c(NA,1,1,NA,0,1,1,1,1,NA),
  v3 = c(2,3,2,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2))
```

I thought about splitting the dataframe by group, and then applying a function for each column, but this didn't seem to work

```
per_missing <- data.frame()
df %>%
  group_by(programme)
  per_missing <- apply(df, 2, function(col)sum(is.na(col))/length(col))
```

Ideally, that information would be written into a new dataframe, where the missingness ratio values of each column are listed for each group. 
And look something like this:

```
res <- data.frame(
  variables = c('v1','v2','v3'),
  A = c(0.0, 1, 0.0),
  B = c(1, 0.0, 0.0),
  C = c(0.0, 0.0, 1)
)

  variables A B C
1        v1 0 1 0
2        v2 1 0 0
3        v3 0 0 1
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't understand how your output is the mean of `NA` values per column. For instance, in column `v1` shouldn't it be `0.3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grouped by 'programme', get the `mean` of NA elements in the other columns, `gather` to 'long' format and `spread` back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(programme) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(is.na(.)))) %>% 
  gather(variables, val, -programme) %>% 
  spread(programme, val)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   variables     A     B     C
#   <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 v1            0     1     0
#2 v2            1     0     0
#3 v3            0     0     1
```